Non-vanishing solutions for a Jacobi equation.
Considering the Jacobi equation
$$y''(t)+k(t)y(t)=0\quad (J)$$
Where $k(t)$ is continuous. If there exist $t_1<0<t_2$ s.t. $\forall t_0\in (t_1,t_2)$, then for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$ there are no nontrivial solutions of $(J)$ s.t. $J(t_0)=J(x)=0$. Then there is a nonvanishing solution of $(J)$?
I think for each $x\in (t_1,t_2)$ there is no $t\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $t$ is a focal point of $x$ i.e. for a solution $y$ of $(J)$ with $y(x)=1,y'(x)=0$, then $y(t)\ne 0$ for any $t\in \mathbb{R}$. But I can't verify this idea by myself.
Indeed, if $(J)$ has no conjugate points i.e. $\forall t\in \mathbb{R}$, there is no nontrivial solution of (J) s.t. $J(t)=0$ and $J(x)=0$ for some $x$, then $(J)$ has nonvanishing solution. We just consider $J(0)=1$ and $J(0)'=\lim_{t\to \infty} J_t'(0)$ where $J_t$ is solution of $(J)$ s.t. $J_t(0)=1$ and $J_t(t)=0$.

Are you familiar with Abel's identity?

Is (J) a scalar equation or a system of equations? For theorems involving a scalar ODE, look up Sturm-Liouville theory online or in an ODE textbook. For theorems involving Jacobi fields along a geodesic in a Riemannian manifold, look in a Riemannian geometry textbook for the chapter on Jacobi fields and curvature.
